# How to optimize querySelectorAll for multiple instances

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following ecmascript which works, but I would prefer to reduce it down to one line, if possible, or just the next best thing, rather than writing querySelectorAll multiple times.  How can I capitalize on this?

```js
    document.querySelectorAll('main .testimonials ul.shadow-box')[2].classList.remove('shadow-box');
    document.querySelectorAll('main .testimonials ul.shadow-box')[1].classList.remove('shadow-box');
    document.querySelectorAll('main .testimonials ul.shadow-box')[0].classList.remove('shadow-box');
```

Comment: [`querySelectorAll.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) or `for(const item of querySelectorAll())`

Comment: @VLAZ, you are assuming that there is no `document.querySelectorAll('main .testimonials ul.shadow-box')[3]` which should remain untouched... ;)

Comment: @secan hence why it's not an answer but a research suggestion as a comment. The question is badly asked as it doesn't really specify this. It seems it's further been widened with unrelated queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forEach()` to execute the query only once and then iterate over the results.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('main .testimonials ul.shadow-box').forEach(function(el) {
  el.classList.remove('shadow-box');
});
```

```css
ul {
  background: red;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.shadow-box {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="testimonials">
    <ul class="shadow-box"></ul>
    <ul class="shadow-box"></ul>
    <ul class="shadow-box"></ul>
    <ul class="shadow-box"></ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array and then `slice` it and then loop through it.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('main .testimonials ul.shadow-box')]
   .slice(0, 3)
   .forEach(x => x.classList.remove('shadow-box'));
```